# how to calculate the array count of 2 fields in mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have collection named posts, which has fields postID, text, likes,shares. **Likes and shares contains array** of **userID** who liked and shared.

```
    {
      postID: 1,
      text: "hello world",
      likes:[ 10001,10002,1004,1006 ],
      share:[10006,10007,10001,10003]
    }
    {
      postID: 2,
      text: "Am robot",
      likes:[ 1004,1006 ],
      share:[10007,10001,10003]
    }
```

I want to calculate the number of likes and shares for each documents in the posts collection.I want to get the **below result**.

```
    {
      postID: 1,
      text: "hello world",
      likes:4,
      share:4
    }
    {
      postID: 2,
      text: "Am robot",
      likes:2,
      share:2
    }
```

please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you query your server and did you check out this already: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/count/

Comment: I would mark as a duplicate, but there is yet to be an up-vote: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822483/mongodb-aggregation-count-items-from-two-arrays

Comment: I dont have any idea how to calculate it. But we can't use count, count is used to calculate number of documents in collections not array in documents.

Comment: @Neil Lunn that doesn't helped me..

Comment: what framework do you use?? or using js ??

Comment: @Arun Aravind framework in the sense? my application framework or any mongodb framework?.

Comment: yeah possibly your application framework. They got drivers for many languages (c#, c++, java etc). You directly query mongodb using their js api or use some frameworks like .net ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches to this, one with aggregate:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$likes"},
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": { 
           "_id": "$_id", 
           "text": "$text", 
           "share": "$share" 
        }, 
        "likes": { "$sum": 1 } 
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$_id.share" },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": { 
            "_id": "$_id._id",
            "text": "$_id.text", 
            "likes": "$likes" 
        }, 
        "share": { "$sum": 1} 
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "text": "$_id.text",
        "likes": "$_id.likes",
        "share": "$share"
    }}
])
```

If you cannot work this out as PHP code then put all the content in the method into a variable $result as a string and decode JSON:

```php
print_r( json_decode( $result ) );
```

Or do it using mapReduce:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function () {
        emit(
            this._id,
            {
                "text": this.text,
                "likes": this.likes.length,
                "share": this.share.length
            }
        );
     },
     function(){},
     { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
 )
```

Comment: I can solve this in PHP, that is not a problem but I wanna find solution in MongoDb so I posted this question. I will try this code.

Comment: It worked. But the problem is if the fields share field doesn't exists in all documents it throws error.

Comment: There is no spelling mistakes. But if the share field doesn't present in all each documents it throws error cannot **read the property of 'length' of undefined near 'this.share.length'**

Comment: @vinothkumar That is why there is the "mapReduce" option. If you have special conditions like missing fields then it is up to you to code it by testing for the presence and putting in a default value. And missing fields are **not** a condition stated in your question. It is not hard to do.

Comment: Am a new bee to mongodb so I don't have much knowledge about mongodb. That is the reason I ask such a question. Anyway I got a spark I will make a fire with. Thanks for your help.